# cannot understand Queue index equation

Tags: data-structures, queue

Suppose we have a circular Queue. Moreover, let us also say it is array based. We would have a front index, rear index, and a size. However, when given the following equation to find rear index, I get rather confused:
rear_index = (rear_index+1) % arraySize;
Can someone please explain to me EXACTLY what is happening? How can this work for enqueueing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Operator % returns the remainder after division.
E.g. 10 % 7 == 3 (7 divides into 10 once with 3 left over), 10 % 3 == 1 (3 divides into 10 3 times remainder 1) etc.

If `size == 10` and `rear_index == 9` (the last element in the array), `rear_index = (rear_index + 1) % 10;` assigns `rear_index = (9 + 1) % 10; // == 0`.  `rear_index` has "looped around" from 9 to 0, the next increment will be to 1, then 2, then...9,0,1,2...

When implementing a queue using a [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) (often also referred to as "ring buffer"), both head and tail indexes are incremented this way and code enforces rules similar to the following (comment from some old code of my own)...

```
/* _head (presumably front_index) => index of oldest entry (next to be returned)
 * _tail (presumably rear_index) => index of next entry to be inserted
 * _head == _tail && queue[tail] != null => queue full
 * _head == _tail && queue[tail] == null => queue empty
```